# Evaluating a notebook programmatically with -ne

Tags: front-end, scripting, command-line

I am running Mathematica 10.2 on an Ubuntu workstation. I would like to be able to evaluate a notebook through the command line, and save its final state so that I can launch evaluation remotely through `ssh` and then take the resulting output.

From the command line `--help`

```
$ mathematica --help
Usage:  /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.2/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica [options] [files]
Valid options:
    ...
    -ne (--notebookevaluate):  Evaluates the input notebooks
    ...
```

it seems an easy task. The `-ne` parameter should make Mathematica evaluate the input notebooks.

But I created a simple test notebook `test.nb` with the following content (**UPDATED**, see EDIT)

```
2 + 2

f[x_] := x^2

D[f[x], x]

Export["test.txt", Table[i,{i,1,10}]]

Plot[f[x],{x,-4,4}]

Export["plot.pdf",%]
```

with an obvious expected output.

Running `mathematica -ne test.nb` creates the `test_out.nb` in my home folder, meaning that the notebook has been evaluated, but the Output is missing.

---

**EDIT** SquareOne methods work in the sense that output is written to the notebook and the notebook file is saved.

I currently have a problem with each method.

1. **Method 1:** *auxiliary notebook*. I cannot get commands that output to file, such as `Export[]`, to work. If evaluated through Method 1 I get a `$Failed` , with no messages. I tried to redirect `$Messages` to `stderr` but it doesn't work neither. The `Export[]` command and `$Messages` redirection work correctly with *Method 2*.
2. **Method 2:** *script*. Graphics is not rendered as Output in the notebook, i.e.  for the before-last command I obtain the following

   ```
   Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Directive[Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], Line[{{-3.999999836734694, 15.999998693877577}, {-3.997546256735669, 15.98037607474136}, ...
   ```

   but the exported graphics, i.e. last command, is the correct PDF file of the plot. The graphics is rendered correctly with *Method 1*, but is not exported to PDF.

**EDIT 2** A workaround for Method 2 has been posted in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96905/5004) and consists in wrapping each graphics in `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Grahics[...], "Output"]]`, e.g.

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Plot[f[x],{x,-4,4}], "Output"]]
```

A more direct solution would still be preferable, but at least this one works nicely. We can define a wrapper to be postfixed to the graphics command:

```
RenderGraphics = CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Output"]]&
Plot[f[x],{x,-4,4}] // RenderGraphics
```

Thanks to GustavoDelfino for pointing this out.

Comment: A solution for the graphics rendering problem in Method 2 (`-script` approach) has actually been found few days before this post by @GustavoDelfino ! See [NotebookEvaluate with InsertResults -> True from the command line](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96852/19960)

Comment: @SquareOne thanks for pointing this out! I confirm this fixes the problem, but of course one needs to wrap every expression involving graphics in `CellPrint[]` which could not be very practical. I'm wondering, may there be a way to programmatically (and transparently) wrap all the cells through the script?

Comment: I actually found the CellPrint is not needed in 10.3. For 10.2 I just added //report at the end of every command and defined report as a CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#,"Output"]]& wrapper

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I have v10.3.0 on OSX and there is no graphics rendering for me with the `-script` approach ! What is your OS ?

Comment: @GustavoDelfino it is still needed in 10.3 under Linux. Thanks, the `//report` is a good idea to improve readability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

- a very simple solution to the OP has been given in this very [duplicate post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133058/19960): all the outputs (in particular graphics) are then correctly inserted in the evaluated notebook without the need to insert/modify the original notebook with special commands.
- also, as asked in the comments, I added a way to monitor in real time the different kind of outputs in the evaluated notebook. In particular, all the regular output can be logged thanks to this [nice workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7083/19960) using `$PrePrint`.

**1/** Here is a test notebook, (***"mynotebook.nb"***), based on the OP example (you can copy/paste the following in a single notebook cell):

```
2 + 2

f[x_] := x^2

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]

Export["m_plot.pdf", %]

f[3]

1/0

Print["Now a 10 sec. pause"]

Pause[10]

Print["print result: ", f[11]]

Export["m_test.txt", Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]]

Echo[1 + 1, "echo result: "]

D[f[x], x]

100 + 1
```

**2/** Here is an example script (***"myscript.m"***) to programmatically evaluate and save the notebook from the command line and also to monitor its different outputs in separate log files. ***Adjust the script to your needs and set the correct file paths:***

```
outputlogfile = OpenWrite["m_output.log", FormatType -> OutputForm];
$PrePrint = (Write[outputlogfile, #]; #) &;

printlogfile = OpenWrite["m_print.log", FormatType -> StandardForm];
AppendTo[$Output, printlogfile];

messageslogfile = OpenWrite["m_messages.log", FormatType -> OutputForm];
AppendTo[$Messages, messageslogfile];

(* ------- Only these 2 lines are needed if no monitoring is needed *) 
SetOptions[First[$Output],FormatType->StandardForm];
UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate["mynotebook.nb",InsertResults->True]] 
(* ------- *)

Close[messageslogfile];$Messages=$Messages[[{1}]];
Close[printlogfile];$Output=$Output[[{1}]];
Close[outputlogfile];
```

**3/** Then just run the previous script from the command line using the ***math kernel*** command line, for example in Mac OS:

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -script myscript.m
```

(Tested with MMA v11.1.1.0)

-> You won't see any output to the console : as expected all the results are directly inserted and saved in the notebook as if you had evaluated the notebook directly by hand. Also as requested in the script, the outputs are duplicated/redirected in real time (see the Pause command) to the given simple text log files which make it possible to monitor the evaluation. In particular, it is only possible to log the `Print` command outputs separately from the rest of the outputs. I was not able to log the `Echo` command ... but this seems to be the [starting point](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143918/19960).

Remark : with the new `wolframscript` command line (added in new MMA versions) the notebook outputs were not inserted inside of it (only the `Echo` , the 1/0 error message and the last command output (100+1 -> 101) were inserted). The Print outputs were also redirected to the console.

---

---

***Previous***

I get the same behaviour than your ("no output") with OSX. I did not even succeed to export some expressions to a file from this notebook (by inserting extra code with `Put[...]` or `Save[...]`)...

However, I've found 2 very simple alternatives using:

> `NotebookEvaluate["yourPathTo/test.nb", InsertResults -> True]`

*(Of course remove the command `NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], "test_out.nb"]` from your `test.nb` for the following tests).*

**1. Notebook approach**

- put the previous `NotebookEvaluate[...]` command in a new notebook
  (`"my.nb"`)
- quit mathematica (later i get segmentation fault if I forget !)
- run from the **command line** : `mathematica -ne my.nb`
  (on OSX `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica -ne my.nb`)

Your `test.nb` notebook has been evaluated, the results were inserted inside it, and it was automatically saved. This means you loose your initial "template" `test.nb`, so be careful to backup it first !

**2. Script approach**

- put `UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate[...]]` command in a text file
  (`"my.m"`)
- run from the **command line** the math kernel : `math -script my.m`
  (on OSX `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -script my.m`)

Your `test.nb` notebook has been modified the same way than in the previous approach.

---

**Remark:** I was not able to use the math kernel approach with the `-noprompt` option. For example on OSX:

```
echo 'UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate["~/test.nb", InsertResults -> True]]' |
 /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -noprompt
```

just hangs indefinetely ... ?  The same command works if i remove the `-noprompt` but this starts an interactive mode which is not the goal here.

Comment: Method 1 works great! With Method 2 I have a `FrontEndObject::notavail` error, but I don't care as long as Method 1 works. However, there seems to be a problem with file output as I can't get `Export[]` to work, see edit.

Comment: @Pincopallino For method 2, are you sure you wrapped the `NotebookEvaluate` command in `UsingFrontEnd` as indicated ?

Comment: oh my, I wrote `UsingFrontend` instead of `UsingFrontEnd`. Now method 2 works perfectly and moreover `Export[]` works as expected. Now I wonder why it doesn't work with method 1

Comment: @Pincopallino I confirm that with method 1 I cannot "export" any file, and that it works for method 2. Also, I tested the notebook with Graphics ... only method 1 works ! I will edit my post to mention that and try to investigate more ...

Comment: it's true, it doesn't work with `Graphics`, in the sense that the output is not the rendered graphics. However, if the graphics object is exported to file it works correctly. Probably, getting method 1 to work would solve all problems. I will keep investigating as well.

Comment: Where you able to get it to print things to the console during the notebook evaluation?

Comment: @M.R. What do you exactly mean "print things" and "console" ?

Comment: I’m using this answer to run net train in a notebook on a remote Linux machine, and I’d like to print the training progress to stdout in the bash shell from which I run the math -script command. @SquareOne

Comment: @M.R. See my update.