# Is there a way to redirect the output from `Echo`?

Tags: streams

The newish function [`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html) is tremendously useful in quick-and-dirty debugging, since you can stick it pretty much anywhere in an expression and get feedback about what's going on. However, like almost everything else in Mathematica (except [`$Messages`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24Messages.html) on Linux), all of the output it generates is sent straight to `STDOUT`.

For interactive use/debugging, this is a minor issue. However, a lot of the time I need to debug scripts that are run on the command line using 
[`wolframscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html), or even launching them on remote machines using `ssh`. This means that being able to direct program output to log files, et c. is invaluable. Experimentation suggests changing [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24Output.html) 
doesn't do the trick at all. Here's what happens if you send `$Output` to a file and use `Print`:

```
stream = OpenWrite[];

Block[{$Output = {stream}},
 Print["foo"]];
(* note: no output appears in notebook *)

ReadLine@Close@stream
(* "foo" *)
```

Here's what happens with `Echo`:

```
stream = OpenWrite[];

Block[{$Output = {stream}},
 Echo["foo"];]
(* note: >> foo appears in notebook *)

ReadLine@Close@stream
(* EndOfFile *)
```

Note redirecting [`$Urgent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Urgent.html) and `$Messages` doesn't help either.     [`$Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Echo.html) isn't, despite the promising name, what I'm looking for at all.

Just to check if I might have missed something, I tried to find other stream variables using the following:

```
Quiet@Select[
  Names["System`$*"], 
  ! FreeQ[ToExpression[#, InputForm, OwnValues], _OutputStream] &]

(* {"$Messages", "$Output", "$Urgent"} *)
```

Comment: If you are running without a FE, `Echo` should just use `Print`. Otherwise, try `Block[{$Output = {stream}, $Notebooks}, Echo["foo"];]`.

Comment: You want to collect those printed by `Echo`? If so, check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99170/1871

Answer (score 2):

As ilian says, when you are running *Mathematica* without a notebook, `Echo` uses `Print` directly.  But with a notebook, there is a bit of sugar added to make the output distinct from normal `Print` statements.  You can see the little orange arrows beside the cell

[image]

If you like, you can redefine it with

```
Unprotect[Echo];
Echo[expression_] := (Print[expression]; expression)
Protect[Echo];
```

giving

[image]

This also makes `Echo` just as fast as `Print`, if that matters to you

Comment: Echo doesn't respect Print actions e.g. PrintToConsole, now it will be tied. Also, all that sugar looks nice in messages window anyway so maybe it could be left.

Comment: I don't use this myself, I also like the "Echo" cell look, but I know someone that does they don't like the ~0.02 seconds it takes for the ```CellPrint[Cell[..``` to work.